# is there a way to create a function to get the size of an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

How to create a function to get the size of an array in C?
Function and array aren't from the same scope.
for example:

```
int func(int arr[]);

int main(){
    int arr[5];
}
```

```
int arr_length(int arr[]){
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    return length;
}
```

The problem with the function above that it treats **arr** as a pointer so it has the size of a pointer

Comment: In `arr_length`, the `arr` parameter **is** a pointer.  In C, the way is to pass the length along with the pointer:  `int arr_length(int arr[], size_t arr_size) { return arr_size; }`

Comment: There's no *portable* way of doing this. But techniques do exist for particular platforms.

Comment: The declaration `int func(int arr[]);` is really the same as `int func(int *arr);`

Comment: @Bathsheba: Are you thinking of something like `malloc_usable_size`, or other things that are only for dynamically allocated memory. If not, what platform provides a way for `func` to get the size associated with its `arr` parameter when the caller defined `int a[3][5]` and passed `a[1]`?

Comment: No way. Add `int` parameter for array size or choose another language.

Comment: @i486, did you mean a `size_t` parameter?  `int` cannot portably represent all possible sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I intentionally shied away from enumerating any techniques, as they become more and more desperate in solving a problem that's best solved by keeping track of the size in a conventional manner. It can't be done in standard C; that's the point I was attempting to make.

Comment: @Yousef Hegazi, Note that with `int func(int arr[]);`, `arr` is **not** an _array_.  It is a _pointer_.

Answer (score 1):

simply pass the array length along with the pointer to the array in the arguments, this is pretty common

```
int some_func(int arr[], int n);
```

Or create a more sophisticated structure for arrays in your application:

```
typedef struct {
  int *vector;
  int length;
  int capacity;
} Array;
```

you can also use my implementations:
https://gist.github.com/arianito/57e668790b723a6e6649d4535e9dcaae

Comment: This is not a good idea. `malloc_usable_size` queries the OS for the amount of memory it has allocated from a previous call to `malloc`. (Meaning it will be slow, and pointless, because you didn't already cache that information, even though you at some point had it when you called `malloc`.)

Comment: true, but desperate times seeks desperate decisions..

Comment: Personally I don't like the use of `int` for `length` and `capacity`. At the time of writing, I'd still wager a fiver on the conjecture that the majority of C programs currently running have a 16 bit `int`.

Comment: This describes appropriate practices, but it doesn't answer the actual question (which I take to be about how to implement function `int arr_length(int arr[])`).

Comment: Sadly I have to tell you, It is not possible, no way around it,